# concatenate on marc/marcEntry[@label='Subject term'

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation

I am trying to write XSLT for a large xml file that contains multiple labels. I would like to concatenate subject terms and there is not a pattern since some items have zero subject terms and others have up to six.
I tried to concatenate on marc/marcEntry[@label='Subject term' however it won't load so I am missing the concept. Here's an example of the xml and xslt.

This is my try

```
<td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="concat(marc/marcEntry[@label='Subject term'],';')"/></td>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="bibtransform.xsl"?>
<report>
<catalog>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="020" label="ISBN" ind="  ">9780691152660 (pbk.)</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="020" label="ISBN" ind="  ">0691152667 (pbk.)</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Langville, Amy N.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Google's PageRank and beyond : the science of search engine rankings / Amy N. Langville and Carl D. Meyer.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">Web search engines.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">Web sites--Ratings and rankings--Mathematical models.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">Internet searching--Mathematical models.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">World Wide Web--Subject access--Mathematical models.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>ZA4226 .L36 2012</callNumber>
<library>WISSER</library>
<item>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>0195501261646</itemID>
<library>WISSER</library>
<libraryDescription>Wisser Library</libraryDescription>
<location>STACKS</location>
<homeLocation>STACKS</homeLocation>
<price currency="$" >27.70</price>
<category1>ETCSC</category1>
<type>BOOK</type>
<numberOfPieces>1</numberOfPieces>
<dateCreated>2012-07-26</dateCreated>
<isPermanent>true</isPermanent>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
</report>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th>Call Number</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>ISBN</th>
<th>Item ID</th>
<th>Hegis</th>
<th>Copy</th>
<th>Location</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="call/callNumber"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Title']"/></td>
<td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Personal Author']"/></td>
<td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Subject term']"/></td>
<td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='ISBN']"/></td>
<td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="call/item/itemID"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="call/item/category1"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="call/item/copyNumber"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="call/item/homeLocation"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you relegated to XSLT version 1.0? What you would want to use is `string-join()`, but it is XSLT 2.0 or greater https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join

Comment: Otherwise, for XSLT 1.0 something such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26274007/14419